# How many combinations

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

In how many many ways can I choose the signs $(+)$ or $(-)$ in order to obtain a number divisible by $5$ from this sum: 
$$1\pm 2 \pm 3 \pm 4 \pm 5 \pm 6 \pm 7 \pm 8 \pm9$$

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! We like to see what work you have done on your own to try and solve a problem so that we can provide the help you need where you need it. I also would recommend you that a look at [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to make your posts look more attractive. Cheers!

Comment: Nice exercise. I will show to my kids.